# Scala slick perform complex sql query

Tags: mysql, scala, orm, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm a new slick user and I'm having trouble creating a slick query.
I need to perform this SQL query with slick:

```
SELECT COUNT(dd.definition_id) accuracy, d.id, d.subject_id, d.creator_id, d.active
FROM definition_detail dd
INNER JOIN definition d
ON dd.definition_id=d.id
WHERE dd.value_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY dd.definition_id;
```

I tried to do it by myself but I managed to create only this:

```
db.run((definition join definitionDetailDAO.definitionDetail on ((d, dd) => d.id === dd.definition_id))
        .map{
          case (d, dd) => (d, dd)
        }.filter(_._2.value_id inSet valuesSeq)
        .map{
          case (d, dd) => (d.id, d.subject_id, d.creator_id, d.active)
        }.result)
```

Which corresponds to this query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.subject_id, d.creator_id, d.active
FROM definition_detail dd
INNER JOIN definition d
ON dd.definition_id=d.id
WHERE dd.value_id IN (1,2,3);
```

Can anyone help me learn it?

P.S. I'm using this dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
```

Comment: dang, can I make a snarky comment like were you thinking about that before you chose slick? Because the thing is, that is not a complex query. They get tremendously worse than that. So find some raw query functionality, and bypass it.

Comment: @Drew What the problem with it?

Comment: The problem is you are frozen for hours cuz an orm is getting in your way.

Comment: Ok, I'll search some way around...

Answer (score 1):

Slick's groupBy compared to SQL is explained here http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html

for getting a value out without aggregating use .max/.min or .head